# Wrong ans given when using Python sympy with inequality

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I make trying to check if a line segment (xy1) intersects with another (xy2).

Here's part of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import Symbol, Piecewise, lambdify, And

x1, y1 = Symbol('x1'), Symbol('y1')
x2, y2 = Symbol('x2'), Symbol('y2')

xx_u1 = 0.5
yy_u1 = 0.053

xx_u2 = 0.51
yy_u2 = 0.052

x_act1 = -2
y_act1 = 0.025

x_act2 = 0.5
y_act2 = 0.025

Ax = x1; Ay = y1; Bx = xx_u1; By = yy_u1; Cx = xx_u2; Cy = yy_u2
tmp1 = Piecewise( (1, (Cy - Ay)*(Bx - Ax) > (By - Ay)*(Cx - Ax)), (0, True))
tmp_1 = lambdify([x1,y1], tmp1, "numpy")
tmp_1_act = tmp_1(x_act1,y_act1)

Ax = x2; Ay = y2; Bx = xx_u1; By = yy_u1; Cx = xx_u2; Cy = yy_u2
tmp2 = Piecewise( (1, (Cy - Ay)*(Bx - Ax) > (By - Ay)*(Cx - Ax)), (0, True))
tmp_2 = lambdify([x2, y2], tmp2, "numpy")
tmp_2_act = tmp_2(x_act2, y_act2)

intersection_tmp1 = Piecewise( (1, tmp1 != tmp2), (0, True))
intersections1 = lambdify([x1, y1, x2, y2], intersection_tmp1, "numpy")
intersection_act1 = intersections1(x_act1, y_act1, x_act2, y_act2)
```

In this case, they shouldn't intersect. So intersection_act1  = 1.
However, I got 0. I only can get 1 if I use:

```
intersection_tmp1 = Piecewise( (1, tmp_1_act != tmp_2_act), (0, True))
```

instead of

```
intersection_tmp1 = Piecewise( (1, tmp1 != tmp2), (0, True))
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Well I don't have the exact answer, but here are some helpful things:
`tmp1 != tmp2` is being immediately evaluated by Python to `False`. Instead use `Ne(tmp1, tmp2)` to create an Unequality (import Ne from sympy). Second, after using `lambdify`, you can use `intersections1.__doc__` to print the generated numpy code.

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I tried as suggested and got:```intersections1.__doc__
Out[4]: 'Created with lambdify. Signature:\n\nfunc(x1, y1, x2, y2)\n\nExpression:\n\nPiecewise((1, ITE(((0.052 - y1)*(0.5 - x1) > (0.053 - y1)*(0.51 - x1)) &...\n\nSource code:\n\ndef _lambdifygenerated(x1, y1, x2, y2):\n    return (select([select([logical_and.reduce((greater((0.052 - y1)*(0.5 - x1), (0.053 - y1)*(0.51 - x1)),greater((0.052 - y2)*(0.5 - x2), (0.053 - y2)*(0.51 - x2)))),True], [False,logical_or.reduce((greater((0.052 - y1)*(0.5 - x1), (0.053 - y1)*(0.51 - x1)),greater((0.052 - y2)*(0.5 - x2), (0```